# Exclude folder from github

Tags: github

I need to exclude the folder App_Data from my Github but i don't know how.

I have a application which saves many files like jpg files in the directory: Source\MyProject\App_data\stored\filename.jpg

Now i need to exclude this from the .gitignore file

I don't know how to do this so i am looking for a example

Comment: Popular gitignore files https://github.com/github/gitignore

Answer (score 36):

1. Create a file called .gitignore in your repository.
2. Add the text "App_Data" to this file.
3. Save.

It should do exactly what you want.  It will exclude files/folders with that string from your local repository path (the path where .gitignore is stored).

Keep in mind, this is not your only option.  I'd read the help document linked below for a better understanding to get exactly what you need accomplished.

See here for more info: [GitHub Help - Ignoring Files](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files)

Comment: is the `/` at the end what makes it know its a directory it should ignore? So if I want to ignore folders that start with `data` should I do `data/` or `data`?

Comment: The slash is a bit different that ignoring the slash. See: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format

Answer (score 11):

Simply put this in your `.gitignore` file (assuming *MyProject* is your git root):

```
App_data
```

Comment: I would say App_data/* is probably better as it covers all subfolders

Comment: is the `/` at the end what makes it know its a directory it should ignore? So if I want to ignore folders that start with `data` should I do `data/` or `data`?

Answer (score 9):

Per https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files

> From time to time there are files you don't want git to track. There
>   are a few methods of telling git what files to ignore.
>
> If you create a file in your repository named `.gitignore` git will use
>   its rules when looking at files to commit. Note that git will not
>   ignore a file that was already tracked before a rule was added to this
>   file to ignore it. In such a case the file must be un-tracked, usually
>   with `git rm --cached filename`
>
> This file can be committed into the repository, thus sharing the rule
>   list with any other users that clone the repository.

Answer (score 2):

In case you need to ignore a whole folder which was already tracked, do not forget to do it recursively with -r.

1. Add foldername/ to .gitignore
2. `git rm -r --cached foldername/`