# How do I push all my files without affecting a specific file in the heroku server?

Tags: javascript, heroku, discord.js

for example, In my heroku server I have Commands.js, Index.js and Prefix.js. I want to push all my files BUT not Prefix.js.
Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you push to heroku your actually pushing to a git repository.
If you didn't touch Prefix.js it will not push it to the repo.

Check which files you have changed by doing:

```
git status
```

you will see a list of files that have been edited, simply add them to be commited.

```
git add filename
```

or `git add .` to add all of them.

then commit and push to heroku master.

Now if for whatever reason you dont wanna push Prefix.js into the heroku repo ever, simply add it to the gitignore file. and it will ignore that file.

Comment: The reason that I want not to push prefix.js is that my Discord bot has a command that changes the prefix, The new prefix of that guild goes to the Prefix file but the thing is that it only updates it on the server and not on my pc. So if I push all the updates somehow it will reset the prefix file from the server and will send my old one instead of that

Comment: also there isnt a gitignore  file

Comment: This might be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16692710/exclude-folder-from-github

Comment: But is it possible to ignore the prefix file from my pc but not the one in the server that gets updated?